# creating mobile menu in php vs in js

Tags: javascript, php, html, responsive-design

Up until now I always tackled the issue of mobile navigation the same way:
Create the menu in php and then manipulate it using css, media queries and js, to act as a mobile menu, when the screen size is narrow, and act as a normal navigation when you are viewing the site on a desktop or a device with as least as much pixels.

But just now I stumbled upon a theme for a cms that is creating the mobile menu on the fly. When I click the mobile menu icon it checks if the mobile menu has already been created and then glues together the menu items with html, checks if there is a search bar, glues that in too if it's necessary, and then appends that to the body.

I was wondering what is the benefit of this?

It would be somewhat reasonable If you were to use a completely another piece of html for the mobile nav, but I would not, and even then, the 170 lines of js is bigger in my opinion than what you would had in a completely separate html menu in size.

Comment: This is the same. The backend creates the menu. Which is hidden on mobile. And then If I want to open the mobile menu in responsive design mode, the js creates another menu and appends it to body, and that is used for the mobile navigation - while the main menu is hidden (in my case the navigation elements are exactly the same in both instances).